# Inject an EJB into a JSF managed bean

Tags: jsf, jboss, ejb, jsf-1.2

I have a war application with some JSF managed beans and EJB for some business logic. I'm using JSF 1.2, JBoss 5 and java 1.6

My managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "managedBean")
@SessionScoped
public class MyManagedBean implements Serializable {
   @EJB(mappedName = "ejbBean")
   public MyEjbBean ejbBean;
   ....
}
```

EJB bean:

```
@Singleton(name = "ejbBean")
public class MyEjbBean {
   ....
}
```

Page not rendered, error:

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Could not dereference object [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: ejb not bound]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JBoss 5 doesn't support `@Singleton` EJB (added in EJB3.1 spec), you can use the JBoss `@Service` annotation to create a singleton.

See the instructions [here](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/reference/build/reference/en/html/jboss_extensions.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped me. Now I have the second problem, jsf tags are not rendering in html tags, but it's another story :)